# Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, objectid

I'm having some trouble with creating an Mongo.ObjectID.

Right now I'm using the Object ID(Value) of each Object I pull from the DB as ID for the table row. When I try to update this particular Item, I get the identifier of this specific item and then I need to parse the ID from String back to an ObjectId.

I did it this way:

```
var objectid = $(event.target).parents('tr').attr('id');
var currentId = new Mongo.ObjectID(objectid);
```

This worked just well.
But now, I recieve this error message:

**Uncaught Error: Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID**

Any ideas?

Comment: is there a chance that the id is null ?

Comment: Nope, I'm loggin it.

Comment: Can you give an example of a string? It should be a 23-character hexadecimal string.